# How do I call a mixin function from another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

`MyMixin.vue` has the method `beginEdit`.

What I'm trying to do is to make `onFirstLineClick` to call myMixin's `beginEdit` depending on the value of `this.folded`.

When I console logged `myMixin.beginEdit`, it is `undefined` and not surprisingly `myMixin.beginEdit()` doesn't work.

Am I missing something needed to use the function? If so, why does `beginEdit` work perfectly on `<span>`?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div
        @click="onFirstLineClick"
      />
      <span
        @click="beginEdit"
      />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myMixin from './MyMixin';

export default {
  name: 'currComponent',
  mixins: [myMixin],
  data() {
    return {
      folded: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFirstLineClick(e) {
      // myMixin.beginEdit() doesn't work
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great thing about `mixin` is that when a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be "mixed" into the component's own options. Which means that inside your component you can call `mixin` method directly like:

```
methods: {
  onFirstLineClick(e) {
    this.beginEdit()
  }
},
```

That is also the reason why you can use `beginEdit()` method on `<span>` directly like:

```
<span @click="beginEdit" />
```

Please also know that in future if you declare a method in this component with same name as `mixin` method name `beginEdit`, then the component's method will take priority and you might see different behaviour. So, make sure to give unique names to `mixin` methods.